# why okhttp RequestBody error about print statement

Tags: java, http, request

I would like to import outer-api, so make the class as below.

However, it occurs the error at the final line.

```
public class WithDrawlApi{

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{ \"to\": \"0xFd4A543c162...843da09B2\", \"amount\":`enter code here`\"1\" }");
    
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url("https://dev.blockchainapi.pro/v1/BTC/transfer")
      .method("POST", body)
      .addHeader("Authorization", "${Access-token}")
      .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
}
```

Comment: What error occurs?

Comment: Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super   constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Comment: {
  try {
   Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  }catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 } fine?

Comment: Then you are ignoring the Exception, other than printing some text to the console. It would be better to rethrow it wrapped in a RuntimeException. But what you seem to be doing, initialising all those fields seems very odd.

Comment: thank you for your response! i solved this problem adding "throws IOException" after method name